# Python: Summing the array elements returned by a loop

Tags: python, arrays, physics

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

AA = np.ndindex(10,10,10)
G = .0000000000066
m = 20000
P0= (20, 0, 0)

for i in AA:   
   print sum(-G*m*(P0[0]-i[0])/(sqrt((P0[0]-i[0])**2+(P0[1]-i[1])**2+(P0[2]-i[2])**2)**3))
```

I'm trying to create a program that applies a function to all elements in an array and then sums all of the new elements together (Actually what I'm trying to do is find the acceleration due to gravity exerted on an observer by a cube from a certain distance away). What the current code is returning is an array of tuples (all of which have been operated on), but I'm having trouble getting the results summed together. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aside: as tempting as it is, you don't want to `import *` from either `numpy` or `pylab`.  That will replace certain built-in functions with others which have slightly different behaviour.  For example, compare `bool(__builtins__.any(False for i in range(3)))` -- which is `False`, as it should be -- with the `True` you get if you try `print any(False for i in range(3))` after a `*` import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator expression inside of `sum()`:

```
print sum(-G*m*(P0[0]-i[0])/(sqrt((P0[0]-i[0])**2+(P0[1]-i[1])**2+(P0[2]-i[2])**2)**3)
              for i in AA)
```

(I moved the `for i in AA` chunk to the next line for readability, but this can just as easily be written as a single line)